# Back propagation with batch for neural network

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

I'm learning about back propagation from a coursera course.
In it they say that back propagation is only done on a single training example at a time. 
This description can be found at this link 
https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning/lecture/1z9WW/backpropagation-algorithm(9 minutes in).

However I am messing around with dl4j. 
In DL4j it seems that they are working with batches. 
In the back propogation they seem to be processing a batch at a time.

How is this possible?

Presumably they have to be able to vectorise the operation below for each layer?
[image link here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgwis.png)